# django including urls

Tags: python, django, include, django-urls

Есть данный код:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Он выдаёт следующую ошибку: `TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`
Проблема в строке: `path('', include('myapp.urls'))`. Как можно заменить её в новых версиях django?

Answer (score 0):

Что то добавили в myapp/urls.py?  пр:   **urlpatterns = [ ]**

- эта ошибка, обычно, получиться из за пустоты myapp/urls.py

Comment: да.............